# How to include time in a mixed effects model

Tags: mixed-model

I am trying to model the progress in proficiency of task completion over time. I would like to model specifically **what is the effect of completing an evaluation and receiving feedback** on the ability to sufficiently complete a task. Proficiency in that task is measured on an ordinal scale that I have categorized into "sufficient" or "insufficient".

At first, I used the following mixed effects model to model this outcome:

```
lme4::glmer(sufficient ~ time*scale(vol_evals) + complexity + (1|task) + (1|subjectID) + (1|raterID), data = df, family = binomial("logit"), control = lme4::glmerControl(optimizer= "bobyqa", optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))
```

- `sufficient` is a boolean value that is `TRUE` if the task is
  completed sufficiently.
- `time` is the day of the year (i.e. 1 to
  365). This model is meant to model progress given feedback throughout
  the duration of a year.
- `vol_evals` is the number of
  evaluations/feedback received by a given `subjectID` up to the time
  point at which the task is being performed.
- `complexity` is an ordinal factor (1-5) that denotes the difficulty of the task.
- `task` is a given task and is modeled as a random effect (there are hundreds of unique tasks).
- `subjectID` is a unique subject identifier. This is modeled as a random effect.
- `raterID` is a unique rater identifier; this is the person providing the feedback. This is modeled as a random effect (the idea being different raters rate either more harshly or more easily.

My hypothesis is that *given two otherwise identical individuals completing a task (same time of the year, same task, same complexity, same rater) the individual that has received more feedback up until that point in time (modeled by `vol_evals`) will be more likely to complete that task sufficiently*.

The model listed above failed to converge. I therefore had to `scale` time:

```
lme4::glmer(sufficient ~ scale(time)*scale(vol_evals) + complexity + (1|task) + (1|subjectID) + (1|raterID), data = df, family = binomial("logit"), control = lme4::glmerControl(optimizer= "bobyqa", optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))
```

The model output appears to make sense:

```
#> Scaled residuals: 
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -8.9518 -0.3503  0.2244  0.4313  3.7796 
#> 
#> Random effects:
#>  Groups    Name        Variance Std.Dev.
#>  task      (Intercept) 1.1871   1.0895  
#>  raterID   (Intercept) 2.5451   1.5953  
#>  subjectID (Intercept) 0.8894   0.9431  
#> Number of obs: 9192, groups:  task, 871; raterID, 794; subjectID, 548
#> 
#> Fixed effects:
#>                              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept)                   1.72910    0.13051  13.249  < 2e-16 ***
#> scale(time)                   0.24813    0.05201   4.771 1.84e-06 ***
#> scale(vol_evals)              0.32502    0.06046   5.376 7.61e-08 ***
#> complexity.L                 -0.90127    0.09190  -9.807  < 2e-16 ***
#> complexity.Q                 -0.13214    0.06343  -2.083   0.0372 *  
#> scale(time):scale(vol_evals) -0.08059    0.05477  -1.471   0.1412    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Correlation of Fixed Effects:
#>             (Intr) scl(t) scl(_) cmpl.L cmpl.Q
#> scale(time) -0.075                            
#> scl(vl_vls)  0.253 -0.421                     
#> complexty.L -0.232 -0.031 -0.041              
#> complexty.Q  0.203  0.006 -0.008 -0.418       
#> scl(tm):(_) -0.067  0.323 -0.226 -0.001  0.008
```

The coefficients make sense - as `time` and `number of evaluations` increases, subjects are more likely to complete a task sufficiently. Likewise, as `complexity` increases, subjects are less likely to complete a task sufficiently.

However, I am not sure how to interpret `scale(time)`. Nor am I certain this is the best way to deal with  the confounding influence of `time` (which is acquired by looking at the date an evaluation is filed). After all, I would expect people to improve over time regardless of if they are receiving feedback.

**Is there a more appropriate way to control for the effect of time in this model?**

Comment: What do you mean *"I am not sure how to interpret `scale(time)`"* ? You have literally interpreted it in the preceeding paragraph. Do you mean you are unsure how to interpret that it is *scaled*. Also note that since it is involved in an interation, it's interpretation is conditional on `vol_evals` being zero.

Comment: How would you describe a 1 unit increase in `scale(time)`? I'm struggling with how - given these results and time being scaled - to describe the effect of time on likelihood of sufficiently completing a task and how this relates to `vol_evals`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scale(time)` standardizes `time` so that it has a mean of zero and a standard deviation of 1.

This means that the regression coefficient for `scale(time)` is the association of a 1 standard deviation change in `time` (unscaled) with the change in the log odds of `sufficient` being true, and since it is involved in an interaction with `scale(vol_evals)` this is conditional on `scale(vol_evals)` being zero.

> Is there a more appropriate way to control for the effect of time in this model?

Edit:  You might try to allow for a non-linear effect of time, for example by introducing a quadratic term